# ng-file-upload: Invalid files being added to 'valid' model when selecting multiple images

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to validate images based on their dimensions, i.e. images are only allowed if they are one of four specific sizes.

```
ngf-dimensions="($width === 669 && $height === 892) || 
($width === 892 && $height === 669) || ($width === 892 && $height === 500) ||
($width === 500 && $height === 892)"
```

It works if I drag a single image at a time - invalid images are added to the invalid list.

But if I drag multiple invalid files at once, for some reason only one file is added to the invalid list, and the others are added to the 'valid' model, but with an error message attached.

For example...

```
<li ng-repeat="f in files">Valid: {{f.name}} {{f.$error}} {{f.$errorParam}}</li>
<li ng-repeat="value in invalidImages">Invalid File: {{value.name}}</li>
```

...results in...

```
Valid: b.png dimensions false
Valid: c.png dimensions false
Invalid File: a.png
```

Below is a fork of one of the ng-file-upload demos - so I'm using a solid base I would imagine.

http://jsfiddle.net/Locotes/n0Ly4aax/3/

How can I add all invalid files to the invalid list? The fact that `$error` is populated must show that the validation is being detected.

**EDIT:**

I updated the fiddle to remove a lot of the extra code that wasn't needed for this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/Locotes/n0Ly4aax/4/

**EDIT 2:**

Opened the following Issue in GitHub as requested (still unresolved):

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/1521

Comment: This seems like a bug with the plugin. Create an issue on the github page please.